# amp element/result does not loading on submit, but on shaking the browser window

Tags: amp-html

I am working on a project where i am using the POLL widgets. It is currently working with combination of api and data is loading inside amp-list tag. When I submit the result via selecting any option the result does not show up, but when i zoom-in/zoom out the browser window, the result loads.

Does anyone experience the same problem with amp or have any solution and suggestions?

Thanks in advance.
[widget-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BQqY.png)  [widget-result-loads-on-browser-zoom-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZvKp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your amp-list hasn't got enough space available if the viewport is too small. Have you defined an overflow button? What also helps is using a fixed-height layout (if the result always has the same height) and placing the amp-list as far as possible to the bottom of the page.

"If amp-list needs more space after loading it requests the AMP runtime to update its height using the normal AMP flow. If AMP Runtime cannot satisfy the request for new height, it will display overflow element when available. Notice however, the typical placement of amp-list elements at the bottom of the document almost always guarantees that AMP Runtime can resize it."

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list

Comment: Here is the url - https://beta.clubcall.com/ (amp/amp)

There is POLL widget on the page. When you submit the option and zoom in/out the page using (ctrl -) then the result loads.

If you can have a look and suggest some help. Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're using a second amp-list to render the result. A better approach might be to return the poll results in the form submit response. Here is a sample for a poll that uses this approach: https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/poll/preview/

Comment: Yeah, changing the amp-list to div submit-success and restructuring the code helps to achieve the desired result. Thanks a lot for the help!